# Symfony2 Understading doctrine query Join

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

So I have no problem understanding queries by using normal doctrine for example like this:

```
        $carousel = $em->getRepository('ApplicationSonataMediaBundle:Gallery')->findOneBy(array('name' => 'Carousel'));
        $featureProducts = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->findBy(array('status' => 1, 'special' => 1));
        $newProducts = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->findBy(array('status' => 1), array('id' => 'ASC'), 8);
```

However I came to the part of my project, where I have a lot of queries(71 in my case). I need to do them by using Join. But I just cant understand some of the parts from it...

I am using this documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#joining-related-records

This is the query:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
        'SELECT p, c FROM AppBundle:Product p
        JOIN p.category c
        WHERE p.id = :id'
    )->setParameter('id', $id);
```

Can someone explain how this is working. I dont understand what does the letters p, c mean. And what exantly is going on with the JOIN. I have little experience with sql queries, since now I only needed the symfony2 doctrine... I think this would help not only me but others to understand. Thanks!

Comment: `p` and `c` are table aliases (see the AppBundle:Product **p** and p.category **c**?).

Comment: This is "normal" Doctrine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your join query will return the result from `Product` and `Category` both entities the result set will return product row where product id matches with `:id` provided parameter and its associated categories , now in dql `p, c` in select are the aliases of your entities **`p`** refers to `Product` entity and **`c`** refers to your `category` entity ,if you have another join in your query like `JOIN p.manufactures m` then if you need product manufactures also then dql select will be like `SELECT p, c, m..`.

Now as doctrine maps your database tables to entities so the join part in dql doesn't involve  `on()` clause because it reads the `on()` part from the [`annotations`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-manytoone) defined on the properties present in your entities like your `Product` entity should have a mapping for category association something like

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="product")
 */
protected $category;
```

and your category entity will point back to product some thing like

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="category")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $product;
```

For more details you can see docs [`Databases and Doctrine`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)